# SStablewriter for python cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, bulk-load

Is there a python variant of the SStable writers for cassandra? I found many java examples,

http://amilaparanawithana.blogspot.com/2012/06/bulk-loading-external-data-to-cassandra.html

Is this still something which is under consideration?

Answer (score 0):

SSTableLoader (https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/bin/sstableloader) is a utility implemented inside Cassandra. The command line in a shell wrapper around calling BulkLoader class. Cassandra was built with Java so all the tools that ship with it use the Java code that comes with Cassandra. I don't think if anyone will be interested to re-invent Cassandra in Python.

Comment: I guess my question was whether there would be a python driver api to the same. I guess not. Thanks!